# Not able to get data in controller on post request data set from front end

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

CreatePeopleForm.jsx

I am using React at the front end and Expressjs at the back end. Creating a simple post request and passing JSON data to the back end via the front end. In the back end if In console: `console.log('from data ',response.json())` getting empty.

I am getting an empty object. Also If I use Postman it works correctly.

Front end Code :

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("foreName: ", forename);
    console.log("SurName: ", surName);
    console.log("role: ", role);
    console.log("team: ", team);
    console.log("email: ", email);
    console.log("image: ", fileName)
    console.log("file: ", file)

    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/people', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                forename: forename,
                surName: surName,
                team: team,
                role: role,
                email: email,
                image: file
            }),
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('from data ', response.json())
        })

};
```

backend :

```js
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // If input fields are empty
    clog('name from controler ', req.role)
    clog('name from controler 2', req.body.forename)
    clog('post\n' +
        req.file);

    if (req.file == undefined) {
        return res.send(`You must select a file.`);
    }

    if (!req.body.forename && !req.body.surname) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Error: cannot add a new member with empty fields. Please try 
            again!'
        });
    }

    const savedPeople = {
        forename: req.body.forename,
        surname: req.body.surname,
        team: req.body.team,
        role: req.body.role,
        email: req.body.email,
        image: req.file.path
    };

    People.create(savedPeople)
        .then(data => {
            return res.status(201).send(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: error.message || "An error has occurred while adding a new 
                member.
                "
            });
        });
};
```